# mongodb with spark got a error code -5

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

I'm now using mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.0.0.jar to read data from mongodb, a sharding cluster which have 5 config server, 5 shard server and 1 mongos. My code is like this:

```
val rdd = MongoSpark.builder().sparkSession(spark).build.toRDD()
rdd.foreach{ x => {
    try{
        dosomething(x)
    }catch{
        case e: Throwable => e.printStackTrace()
    }
}}
```

and my spark config is:

```
.config("spark.cores.max", 60)      
.config("spark.executor.cores", 12)
.config("spark.executor.memory", "32g")
.config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://192.168.12.161:27017/datab.origin2")
```

There are 27,000,000 documents in the collection, when the spark application start the rdd have 2500 partition. After running for a while, I got an error code -5 on my driver:

> Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCursorNotFoundException: Query failed with
>   error code -5 and error message 'Cursor 2639909050433532364 not found
>   on server 192.168.12.161:27017' on server 192.168.12.161:27017 at
>   com.mongodb.operation.QueryHelper.translateCommandException(QueryHelper.java:27)
>   at
>   com.mongodb.operation.QueryBatchCursor.getMore(QueryBatchCursor.java:213)
>   at
>   com.mongodb.operation.QueryBatchCursor.hasNext(QueryBatchCursor.java:103)
>   at
>   com.mongodb.MongoBatchCursorAdapter.hasNext(MongoBatchCursorAdapter.java:46)
>   at
>   scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.hasNext(Wrappers.scala:42)
>   at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893) at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336) at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1951)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1951)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99) at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I read the spark log on the worker, this is the first time 433 task start and the first time it return error:

> 17/07/17 19:14:23 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 433
>
> 17/07/17 19:14:23 INFO Executor: Running task 433.0 in stage 0.0 (TID
>   433)
>
> 17/07/17 19:37:31 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 433.0 in
>   stage 0.0 (TID 433) com.mongodb.MongoCursorNotFoundException: Query
>   failed with error code -5 and error message 'Cursor
>   2639909048849185072 not found on server 192.168.12.161:27017' on
>   server 192.168.12.161:27017

and this in mongs log:

> 2017-07-17T19:24:49.677+0800 I QUERY    [ClusterCursorCleanupJob] Marking cursor id 2639909048849185072 for deletion, idle since 2017-07-17T19:14:46.055+0800

I search for the error code -5 and know that it happens when cursor not use for 10 minutes, but other partitions only need 3-4 minutes to complete the processing. 
When I use java driver I can use `noCursorTimeout()` to avoid this problem, how can I solve this problem when I use mongo-spark-connector? Or what can I do with my sharding cluster to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I run spark on local with config `spark.master=local[16]`. I spent a lot of time on searching in Internet to find the solutions, but nothing found. At last, I tried to set `spark.master=local[1]`, It worked!

Comment: Just to add some possible explanation to the `solution`: if you're launching 16 threads instead of one, you're probably opening more connections to mongo which can make it more likely to have connection issues.